# Halachic limitations on testing Hashem with Tzedaka

Tags: halacha-theory, money, tzedakah-charity, parnassah-livelihood

THe Gemmorah ([Taanis 9a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Taanit.9a?lang=bi)) discusses the idea of testing Hashem with charity/tithes and brings proof from Tanach (Malachi 3,10) - you give your charity and Hashem maximizes your "earnings":

> אשכחיה ר' יוחנן לינוקא דריש לקיש אמר ליה אימא לי פסוקיך א"ל עשר תעשר א"ל ומאי עשר תעשר א"ל עשר בשביל שתתעשר אמר ליה מנא לך א"ל זיל נסי
>   אמר ליה ומי שרי לנסוייה להקב"ה והכתיב (דברים ו, טז) לא תנסו את ה'.
>   א"ל הכי אמר רבי הושעיא חוץ מזו שנאמר (מלאכי ג, י) הביאו את כל המעשר אל בית האוצר ויהי טרף בביתי ובחנוני נא בזאת אמר ה' צבאות אם לא אפתח לכם את ארובות השמים והריקותי לכם ברכה עד בלי די...
>
> is it permitted to test the Holy One, Blessed be He? But isn’t it written: “You shall not test the Lord your God” (Deuteronomy 6:16)? Rabbi Yoḥanan said to the boy that Rabbi Hoshaya said as follows: It is prohibited to test God in any way, except in this case of tithes, as it is stated: “Bring the whole tithe into the storeroom, that there may be food in My house, and test Me now by this, said the Lord of hosts, if I will not open for you the windows of heaven, and pour out for you a blessing that there shall be more than sufficiency”

Shu"A Yo"D 247:

> הצדקה דוחה את הגזירות הקשות וברעב תציל ממות כמו שאירע לצרפית:
>   **הגה:** **והיא מעשרת ואסור לנסות הקב"ה כי אם בדבר זה שנאמר ובחנוני נא בזאת** וגו' (טור מגמרא פ"ק דתענית) וי"א דוקא בנתינת מעשר מותר לנסות הקב"ה אבל לא בשאר צדקה (ב"י דכך משמע מש"ס שם)

What are the contemporary limitations to testing Hashem with charity:

- Starting the test - hould one advertise it or it's forbidden to advertise, should it be in writing, or saying or thought is enough?
- How long should one wait until rendered as a success/failure?
- What can be considered as a success - should I get back what I gave or multiplies of it?
- How many times can one test Hashem - on a daily basis, weekly, monthly or less?
- (Probably a completely different question) What's the point of testing Hashem if there are tens of other Hashem's considerations for providing one's Parnasa (like מזונותיו של אדם קצובים לו מר"ה לר"ה)?

A related question: ["does-promising-salvation-in-return-to-a-donation-border-on-fraud"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100381/does-promising-salvation-in-return-to-a-donation-border-on-fraud).